# Powershell exclude items when copying not working

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am willing to copy recursively from one dir to another by excluding some items that cause errors if copied.

It was working fine when I only had the "System Volume..." and "RECYCLE.BIN" values in "$Excluir" variable, but, now I need to exclude every item that starts with a dot "." so I wrote the loop you see after it that adds new values to the $Excluir variabl.

Now the "-Exclude" parameter forgets excluding the new values, in this case these values are names of files and directories that start with a dot "."

Sorry if my english causes confusions.

This is my code:

```
$RutaOrigenFicheros = "E:\"
$RutaTempFicheros = "A:\ENTRADA\TMP\"

$Excluir = @( "System Volume Information","`$RECYCLE.BIN")

$ElementosOcultosUnix = Get-ChildItem $RutaOrigenFicheros -Name -Recurse -Include ".*"

foreach ($i in $ElementosOcultosUnix){
  if ($i -match "\\")
  {
    $elemento = $i -split "\\"
    $n = ($elemento.length) - 1
    $Excluir += $elemento[$n]
  }
  else
  {
    $Excluir += $i
  }
}

Write-Host $Excluir

Copy-Item -Path $RutaOrigenFicheros* -Destination $RutaTempFicheros -Recurse -Force -Exclude $Excluir -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Are you only copying files, or are directories included?

Comment: Its recursive so both of them

Comment: I was asking more for intent.  So you want all files/folders except those that start with a period, or the two named files in your example: System Volume Information and $RECYCLE.BIN ?

Comment: System Volume Information and $RECYCLE.BIN are fixed, the loop adds more strings to the variable "$Excluir", these strings start with a dot and are names of directories and files that I need to exclude. Then I take this $Excluir variable and use it with the parameter -Exclude. Sorry if I cant explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic isn't very clear (or doesn't make sense).  Here's what I think you're trying to accomplish with your code:

```
$Destination='A:\Temp\'

$Exclude = Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\' -Recurse -Force |
  Where-Object { $_.FullName -like '*System Volume Information*' -or
                 $_.FullName -like '*$RECYCLE.BIN*' -or
                 $_.FullName -like '*\.*' }

Write-Host $Exclude.FullName

Copy-Item -Path 'E:\*' -Destination $Destination -Recurse -Force -Exclude $Exclude.FullName -ErrorAction 'Stop'
```

Comment: What do you mean with my logic isnt clear? I am pretty new to powershell programming but I see my code pretty understandable. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: I have tested your code and doesnt work, its not excluding. Maybe I explained myself incorrectly. I need to exclude System Volume Information and RECYCLE.BIN directories that are created by NTFS filesystem, and, I need to exclude "possible" files or directories that start with a .

Comment: For example, my $Excluir variable final value after the loop has these values as an array: System Volume Information, $RECYCLE.BIN, .file1.txt, .file2.txt, .dir1

Comment: Just realised -Exclude works fine with dirs but doesnt exclude files